# Making a observable variable as null

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a an observable variable of the following format:

```
var obvar = ko.observable("");

obvar({view:'dummy.html',model:'dummymodel'});
```

In one of my checks I want to empty the contents , if variable "obvar" contains

```
{view:'dummy.html',model:'dummymodel'}.
```

I tried `obvar("");` but its not happening.
`obvar ="";` would convert it to normal string.
How to empty the contents?

Comment: Interesting - but obvar("") does work. Are you having a problem with self? or different scopes? https://jsfiddle.net/brianlmerritt/vojte1gg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first code snippet:

> ```
> var obvar = ko.observable("");
>
> obvar({view:'dummy.html',model:'dummymodel'});
> ```

has a special but important feature. The `obvar` observable first contains a `string`, and after the second line it contains an `Object`.

Your requirement that you mention is (emphasis mine):

> ...I want to *empty the contents*, if variable `obvar` contains `{view:'dummy.html',model:'dummymodel'}`

It's unclear to me what you mean by "empty" the contents, and perhaps to you as well (since you've tried `obvar("");`, which in a sense "empties" the content, but it had not the desired result).

At any rate, here are two ways to do it, in a *runnable* snippet so you can see proof that it's working:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  var obvar = ko.observable("");
  obvar({view:'dummy.html',model:'dummymodel'});
  
  self.obvar = obvar; // Expose it so the view can demo the workings.
  
  function canEmptyContents() { 
    // empty the contents if variable "obvar" contains {view:'dummy.html',model:'dummymodel'}
    return obvar().view === 'dummy.html' && obvar().model === 'dummymodel';
  }
  
  self.option1 = function() {
    if (canEmptyContents()) {
      obvar("");
    }
  };
  
  self.option2 = function() {
    if (canEmptyContents()) {
      obvar({ dummy: "", model: "" });
    }
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: option1">Option 1: empty with string</button>
<button data-bind="click: option2">Option 2: empty with empty object</button>
<hr>
Debug info: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```